# Improving NHibernate performance with too many objects in session

Tags: performance, nhibernate

Our app was originally built with NHibernate and its limitations of batch processing in mind. However, over time it has transformed into a data cruncher and we are observing a significant performance decay.

The session ends up having to maintain about 1000 objects or more and our profiling has revealed that auto flushing and dirty checking are the biggest offenders here. We tried shutting auto flush and managing it ourselves on Save/Update operations but that led to disastrous performance for a batch save/update.
We're now looking at the option of evicting unrequired objects from the session.

1. I came across 2nd level-cache eviction method (`sessionFactory.Evict(typeof(Cat));`) which lets us evict by type but we do not use a 2nd level cache. Can I still use this method to evict objects from the 1st level cache?
2. I also read about one pattern of fetching objects, evicting them from session, and then reassociating them, if needed, with session by calling Update() on them. Is this a recommended and accepted pattern cause I also read that NH3 has put up a wall to this? (We can still use it as we have not upgraded to NH3)

While we realize that we are not using NHibernate in the best way, we are just looking to improve the current situation somehow. Answers to the above questions and any other suggestions/recommendations are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**
After looking at NH documentation and code, I realize that 1 is probably not possible.   I'm still looking at some pointers or tips on using Evict(). I was able to drastically reduce the number of objects in a session. But still do not know if there is a price to pay  while updating or deleting evicted objects. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing more about your requirements but maybe you could use IStatelessSession.  It doesn't have a 1st level cache to worry about.

Ayende has a good post on using it for bulk operations
[here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/22/nhibernate-perf-tricks.aspx)

Comment: We have looked at using a Stateless session but it is not a possible solution immediately as it would require some rework of the architecture. Thanks for your tip Jason.
I am still looking at `Session.Evict()` as a possible life-saver and wondering if you had any inputs on using it as described in the 2nd point.

Comment: The only times I've used Session.Evict is when I knew I wouldn't need to do anything else with the entity and wanted to free up some memory (this is useful for bulk operations).  Maybe you can use ISession.GetSession to create a child session.  It shares the same connection but keeps its own list of entities to flush

Answer (score 0):

Why not use more sessions, instead of one large one?  That, in conjunction with turning off autoflush has helped me in the past.  Also, you should really think about using HQL for bulk updates if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is old, but I just came across this while looking for something else -- having just solved this.  I did solve as Trent mentioned, by using more than one session.  I would create one session to fetch all of the objects I wanted, then closed that session.  The case I had, was iterating through the list and operating on each object and trying to commit on each iteration.  I would then create the foreach over my list, creating and disposing of a new session inside the loop, reattaching my object from the list to the new session.  That took a process that was taking about 2.5 hours down to 2 minutes 40 seconds!

See this article for the inspiration to how I solved it -- although not exactly as I have unit of work wrappers around NHibernate:

http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2013/03/21/attaching-disconnected-entities-in-nhibernate-without-going-to-the-database.aspx